# how to get context of a text file and add it to html file by python using Flask

Tags: python, flask

this is the exercise(you can use only two html templates (the index and the movie). When the user navigates to a movie specific page the description and title must be read from a file called {movie_id}.txt within the project dir and then passed to movie template.)
i tried this ===>>

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/marvel")
def marvel():
    with open("marvel.txt") as file:
        return render_template("movie.html", text=file.read())
```

however it only printed the html codes inside the text file and didnt use it as html codes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the text file contains html tags, which are automatically escaped within the template. Use the Jinja2 filter [safe](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.safe) within the template to suppress this behavior.

`{{ text | safe }}`

An alternative to declare content outside of the template as safe is the following. You can find the documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Markup).

```
from flask import Markup

@app.route("/marvel")
def marvel():
    with open("marvel.txt") as file:
        html = Markup(file.read())
        return render_template("movie.html", text=html)
```

Note that the default behavior has been implemented for security reasons and you are aware of what the contents of the text file can do within your page.

Perhaps your task allows you to reconsider your data structure and application design so that you can format the html entirely within the template and not within a plain text file.